# Remove whitespace and line break from autocomplete's li element

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete, line-breaks, removing-whitespace

When focused on an auto sugggestion that has a line break in it's  it renders with extra whitespaces only in the input.
However in the suggestion select it shows fine.

Any solution? tried `white-space: nowrap` both on the input and on the li element and tried running a function to remove from the li any extra whitespaces 
using `replace(/<br\s?\/?>/, '')`

[This is how it looks in the console:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6jKz.png)

[And this is how the input and the suggestion looks like:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ5uZ.png)

This is the autoComplete code I've written:

```js
$(function() {  

  $( "#searchPageQuery" ).autocomplete({
    source: getSuggestionsSearchPage,
    autoFocus: false,
    minLength: 2,
    select: function ( event, ui ) {
      window.location = ui.item.url;
      }
  });
});


function getSuggestionsSearchPage ( request, response ) {
  var params = $("input:checked[name='labels']").serializeArray();
  var query = { name:"q", value:request.term };
  params.push( query )
  var params1 = jQuery.param( params );
  $.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: "@{AutocompleteSearchR}",
  data: params1,
  success: function(data) {
    var newdata = data.suggestions;
    response(newdata);
    }
  });
  }
```

Comment: Can you inspect the code for the input and the select and post the HTML for that.  It might have something to do with block vs. inline elements for spaces / tabs between the elements in your markup.  The raw code would help.

Comment: Can you tell me what your newdata looks like, sample data is enough. You might want to make above regular expression replace on the data itself for this to work. If your data has the format: [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ], then the value needs to be formatted.